# Cannot clear session using javascript in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session, servlets

created session from login.jsp page using servlet

```
String msg = "";
        HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
       // if(sess != null)

        //sess.invalidate();
        if (sess.getId() != null) {
            sess.setAttribute("uname", uname);
            sess.setAttribute("pwd", pwd);
        }
```

retrived  session in other jsp page using

```
<b> Welcome ${uname}</b>
```

logout hyperlink

```
<a href="login_ml.jsp" id="logout_link" onclick='lgt()'>Logout</a></td>
```

javascript to clear session

```
function lgt(){
                var logout = document.getElementById("logout_link");
                logout.session.clear();
                alert("logout");
                }
```

Comment: use sess.invalidate();

Comment: but javascript is in other .js file.

Comment: Your client side will need to make a server request to invalidate the session on server side.

Comment: The Javascript merely gets the `a` element in the HTML whose id is `logout_link`. Why do you expect an `a` element to have a `session` attribute?

Comment: can you give one example? how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

We cannot clear session directly from JS code . You have to call another JSP page  will invalidate that session :

**Javascript Function :**

```
 function destroySession() {
        window.location = "killSession.jsp";
   }
```

**killSession.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Log out</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
session.invalidate();
%>
User has been Logged out sucessfully!!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just called that javascript using <a href="login_ml.jsp" id="logout_link" onclick='destroySession()'>Logout</a></td>                       but it is not working

Comment: is it calling the JPS page ? what you have written in JSP /

Comment: <a href="login_ml.jsp" id="logout_link" onclick='destroySession()'>Logout</a> this is the link i have written in jsp.

Comment: No. I am talking about `killSession.jsp`.

 `xmlhttp.open("GET","killSession.jsp",false);`

Comment: hey, @Rehman i got you.. i tried using "page1.jsp1"   which is the name of the jsp page i have called the session using ${uname}.

Comment: @user5277872 Edited my answer. Have a look . Its much easier

Comment: thanks rehman :) it worked.. but it gives error when user tries to modify something.. i want if user press the back button it does not allow to do so.